# executing method in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can't find what's wrong with this.

```
def self.transfer(from, to, quantity)
 transaction(from, to) do
   from.withdraw(quantity)
   to.deposit(quantity)
 end
end
```

In the console this works

`Stock.transaction do; sone.deposit(10); stwo.withdraw(10); end` but if I do

`Stock.transfer(sone, stwo, 10)` I receive `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`transaction` class method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) takes a single (optional) options Hash as an argument but you're passing it `from` and `to`:

```
transaction(from, to) do
```

You're console test just uses `Stock.transaction` without any arguments at all. Your `transfer` class method should probably look more like this:

```
def self.transfer(from, to, quantity)
  transaction do
    from.withdraw(quantity)
    to.deposit(quantity)
  end
end
```